# Django 2.1 template img src is not working

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

I want to display images on my Django template file but the images are broken. All the images are uploaded in media static files but they cannot be displayed in my template file, when I go to Django admin page and click on the image link, here is the error message I got:
[Page not found(404)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roczc.png)

Can anyone please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is the template file "post_detail.html":

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-6">

        {% if instance.image %}

        <img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" alt="image" class="img-thumbnail">

        {% endif %}

        <div class="post-detail-item text-justify"><p> {{ instance.get_markdown }} </p> </div>

    </div> 

</div>
```

Here is my app => posts views.py:

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)

    initial_data = {
        "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
        "object_id": instance.id
    }
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        parent_obj = None
        try:
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get("parent_id"))
        except:
            parent_id = None

        if parent_id:
            parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
            if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
                parent_obj = parent_qs.first()


        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            user = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            content = content_data,
                            parent = parent_obj,
                        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.content_object.get_absolute_url())


    comments = instance.comments
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
        "comments": comments,
        "comment_form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

Here is my app => posts urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import (post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
)   urlpatterns = [
path('', post_list, name='list'),
path('create/', post_create),
re_path('(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/', post_update, name='update'),
re_path('(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/', post_delete),
re_path('(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', post_detail, name='detail'),  ]
```

Here are posts models.py and upload_location :

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    PostModel = instance.__class__
    new_id = PostModel.objects.order_by("id").last().id + 1
    return "%s/%s" %(new_id, filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True, width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    read_time =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Here are my settings.py and the main_app urls.py:

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

main_app urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('comments/', include(('comments.urls', 'comments'), namespace='comments')),
    path('register/', register_view, name='register'),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('', include(('posts.urls', 'posts'), namespace='posts')),]  


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: What is responsible for serving media files at MEDIA_URL?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT is responsible for serving media files, and in my main_app urls.py I have defined MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn"). When I upload the images on my blog they appear in the directory media_cdn but they cannot be displayed on my blog.

Comment: Check the path is correct or not by adding `{{ instance.image.url }}` in a <p> tag. And you can remove this line `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` from `urlpatterns +=` It should be `if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: I just checked the path, it is correct "/media/4/Chercher-Dieu.jpg" and I also removed the line you just mentioned but I still got the same error. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files aren't served in development by default.

Add this on to the end of your URL patterms:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

However, this isn't suitable for production, so you will need some other method when you get to that stage (serving from nginx or a CDN or whatever).

Comment: I have already added this at the end of my URL patterns but I still got the same error, I just edited the code above. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I'm assuming you're using runserver and you've restarted that since you made the change? I'd try uploading another file in the admin and seeing if it shows up, maybe one of the directories have changed as you've been trying to fix it.

Comment: I have restarted it after making changes but still got the same error. If one of the directories have changed how could I fix this?

Comment: Well you would have to move any files from the old directory into the new one - but I'd just try uploading a new file - if it still doesn't work this isn't your issue